# How to find $y'$ when $y + x \cos(y)=x^2y$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am going through Calculus 1 review for my Calculus 2 class, and I am not sure how to find $y'$ when $y + x \cos(y)=x^2y$.

It seems like it would require me to get $y$ by itself on one side of the equation, but I don't know how to extract it from $\cos(y)$.

How can I get $y$ into a position where I can differentiate and find $y'$?

Comment: You don't have to solve for $y$ as a function of $x$ explicitly. Instead use implicit differentiation. It will look something like $$y'+\frac{d}{dx}(x\cos(y))=\frac{d}{dx}(x^2y).$$Now use product rule etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use implicit differentiation, that is, with

$y + x \cos y = x^2y, \tag 1$

we may take the $x$-derivative using the product and chain rules:

$y' + \cos y - xy'\sin y = 2xy + x^2y'; \tag 2$

a little algebraic maneuvering yields

$(1 - x\sin y - x^2)y' = 2xy - \cos y, \tag 3$

so assuming that

$1 - x\sin y - x^2 \ne 0, \tag 4$

we have

$y' = \dfrac{2xy - \cos y}{1 - x\sin y - x^2}. \tag 5$

Not knowing $y$ as a function of $x$ makes it a challenge to simplify further; thus, I content myself with $y'$ as a function of *both* $x$ and $y$.

Answer (score 2):

Differentiating both sides yields

$$y' + \cos(y) - x y' \sin(y) = 2xy + x^2 y',$$

so

$$y'(1 - x \sin (y) - x^2 )= - \cos(y) + 2xy$$

and

$$ y' = \frac{- \cos(y) + 2xy}{1 - x \sin(y) - x^2},$$

provided $1 - x \sin(y) - x^2 \neq 0$.